# How to create a Calendar using Overlay in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, calendar

I've created a calendar using a package but it is in popup but i need overlay to be used , how to achieve this?

[image: Calendar Image]

I've created a calendar using a package but it is in popup but i need overlay to be used , how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share some code that you've worked on and what the package was that you used. Nobody will be able to help you until you do.

Comment: Add the code that you have written. also, add a sample image of what you want to achieve.